# Error when instantiating AVCaptureDeviceInput

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturedevice

I'm building an app with a bottom bar that has different views.
An RSS feed view opened by the bottom left corner button and a custom camera from the bottom right corner button.
By compiling the app and running it in the simulator, when I tap on the camera button, the app freezes and on the line

```
let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
```

Xcode shows the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value.

This is the function:

```
 func beginSession () {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

How can I fix the issue? Thank you!

Comment: How is `captureDevice` initialized? It seems like that might be an implicitly unwrapped optional, hence the error, but without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no one can tell for sure.

Comment: This is how I initialized it: var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!

Comment: Then the issue clearly is that you didn't actually assign a value to `captureDevice`, but it is `nil`.

Comment: Alright, thank you. How can I fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

Since `captureDevice` is defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional, unless you actually assign a non-nil value to it before the first time you access it, you will receive a runtime error. You shouldn't be using implicitly unwrapped optionals unless you have a very good reason to do so.

You should simply define `captureDevice` as a non-optional and assign a value to it. You can tweak the input argument or use a different initializer of `AVCaptureDevice` based on your exact use case.

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

func beginSession(){
    do {
        guard let captureDevice = captureDevice else {return}
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it shows this error (as a suggestion to fix it) Value of optional type 'AVCaptureDevice?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? Insert '!'.

Comment: @TommasoPirola updated my answer